# Kotlin generics wildcard with extend

Tags: generics, kotlin

So, I've been trying to implement some Java in Kotlin, and I faced this challenge of passing arguments to wildcarded generic class methods.
For example:

```
interface A
class B<in T : A> {
    fun pass(e: T) {
    /* do something */
    }
 }

class C {
    private val things = mutableListOf<B<*>>()
    fun test(e: A) {
        things.get(0)?.pass(e) // This doesn't work, since wildcard B generic wants Nothing, since Nothing can be safely passed to it.
         // but, I know that `e` is passable to `pass` method, since
         // its an impl of A
    }
 }
```

It's possible to implement this in Java, but is it in Kotlin? If so, how should I do this?

Comment: How would you implement it in Java? You don't know what the generic type of the B is, so you don't know if the `e` you pass is of the right type.

Comment: I did find something similar to `ArrayList<B>` without specifying generic of `T`, and it does compile and work as expected. Though, I have no idea how that works.

Comment: Yes, but it's using a raw type, and thus isn't type-safe.

Comment: Ah, as Kotlin's generics are type-safe, this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: AFAIK, no, not as is. Java generics are type-safe, too. But if you use an ArrayList<B>, you're not using B as a generic type. You're using it as a aw type, effectively saying the compiler: forget about type safety here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: You can do `fun <T: A> test(e: T) {
        (things.get(0) as B<T>).pass(e)
    }`, but it's of course not type-safe.

Comment: Well, I can't exactly do that, since `test` in the actual project overrides a method (so I can't change signature). But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that T must extend A, you can specify that in 'C.things' initialization.

```
private val things = mutableListOf<B<A>>()
```